# how to add new layout xml properly?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, view

I'm writing an android application using eclipse.

I have a main activity called MenuActivity that shows a menu.
when the user press play it starts the game activity.

I created a new layout at res/layout/game.xml.
I want the GameActivity to use that layout using `setContentView()`. the problem is that
R.layout. doesn't see any of the new layout xml i added.

what am I missing? the xmls are not views? am i doing this all wrong?! :)

any information would be greatly appreciated.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you build the project? And did eclipse import Android.R instead? Because that can cause a big problem. Is there any errors in any XML files which is preventing a build? All possibilities

Comment: I deleted the import to android.R and it imported the proper one and now it works :)

Comment: Accepted answer? And thats just one of the problems eclipse seems to have, if you import before the first time you build and the R file isn't present it just assumes that the R file for android is the one you want to use.

Comment: actually if i remember correctly it let me choose and i chose wrong :)

Comment: Yeah sometimes that happens :P, its just like if you want to use a support library and you import and it comes up whether you want to use the support library or the normal one

Answer (score 0):

Just go to Projects -> Clean it rebuild your project and regenerate R.

Comment: But would it re-do the imports? Ps. the answer below solved the problem.

Comment: it rebuilding your project's R, if you create something it defines automatically on R.class, if doesn't you have to do manually, using clean function

Comment: Thats what I thought, the import part was what the problem was, it was importing the android.R file instead.